# Civ 6 Output Graphs

Tags: civilization-6

I would like to obtain plots of my various outputs per turn in a Civ 6 game to see how I am doing - and compare strategies. Like to see how much science I produced, culture accumulated per turn, etc. Is there a way to do this - I seem to remember something in earlier version of Civ.

Failing that is there a mod that would do it? Or would this be  possible with a Lua Mod?

Comment: AFAIK, mod requests are off topic, but, in terms of graphs, my best guess is for you to take screenshots of end game graphs that show you your per turn information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CIVIG 2](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1670866401) is a mod that handles this for Civ VI.

[image: screenshot of CIVIG 2]